# Can I save Thunderbolt Display Arrangement so it is different depending on which Thunderbolt I connect?

Tags: display, thunderbolt, thunderbolt-display

I recently migrated from a 2013 MacBook Pro to a 2016 MacBook Pro, both running Mojave 10.14.3.  I connect my laptop to a Thunderbolt 2 display.  I have one Thunderbolt at my office, and a second one at home.  Because of the way each workspace is arranged, I put my laptop to the right at home, and to the left at work.  At some point several years ago, some knowledgeable person must have helped me configure the display setup so I did not have to open Preferences and adjust the Thunderbolt Display Arrangement every time I travel between work and home. Now that I have migrated to a newer laptop, whatever file that captured that configuration is gone.  I can find lots of advice online for daisy-chaining multiple displays at once, but that's not what I want to do. I'd appreciate any suggestions for setting a display arrangement so it adjusts based on the identity of the hardware. I do plan to re-arrange my desk if I can't sort this out, but that's plan B.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Check out the tool I wrote called [displayplacer](https://github.com/jakehilborn/displayplacer) for setting monitor configurations via profiles. Since your goal is to treat the same model monitor differently you may need to use the contextual screen ids instead of persistent screen ids. Be sure to read the Notes section on GitHub for more info on this.